# Is there a clean way to create runtime checks with .NET 6 that email the dev team any issues, but don't throw?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

We have a function `Assert.hard(condition)` that will throw if false.

I want to also make a function `Assert.soft(condition)` that won't throw, but will email / Slack the dev team as appropriate, in case of non-fatal but unexpected runtime conditions.

The only way I see so far, given .NET practices I'm aware of, is to register an `IAssert` service, and add it as a member on each Controller where I might want to assert (or just on a `BaseController` class and inherit that in my other controllers).

The issue with that is that I'd have to plumb the `IAssert` dependency all over into helper methods and unrelated tools classes, just to be able to make some runtime check.  That seems like a huge antipattern - the caller should not need to be concerned about whether some math or other utility function needs to make a runtime check.  In a program with lots of these checks - which are generally very healthy for the system - basically every function will need an extra `IAssert` service param just to operate, bloating the code and making it less readable (since that dependency doesn't have anything to do with the function's purpose - it's very much incidental).

Is there a cleaner way to do this?  I just want to call `Assert.Soft(condition)` and get a notification if it fails, while the program continues on, without having to pass an `IAssert` param all over the code base.

Comment: This seems exactly analogous to injecting an `ILogger` interface where needed, which is pretty much standard for modern frameworks.   (See for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)  Or in other words, I do not see this as an antipattern at all.

Comment: Note that you can actually make your tool classes part of DI pipeline i.e. inject and resolve them.

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks for the tip - can you specify any further?  I'm not sure how I would access the tool class from a helper function, for example, unless it's static.  I'm coming from some years in JS land and wrapping my head around some .NET specifics.

Comment: @Freewalker I think Guru is talking about a situation where you have a utility class, say `MyMathFormulas` with a static method `CalculateSolution` where you want to perform these assertions.  You could instead make the method non-static and inject an _instance_ (possibly singleton scoped) of `MyMathFormulas` wherever you want to call `CalculateSolution`.  `MyMathFormulas` in turn would inject into its constructor your `IAssert` interface.

Comment: I agree with comments that injecting a service is probably the right solution. An alternate would be to have a static Assert class which gets set up at run-time, e.g. details of who to email, etc., and have the `Assert.soft(...)` method. You could then use a set-up method to inject any services into the static Assert class (e.g. `ISmtpClient`, etc). Probably a bit of an anti-pattern, but it gives global access to `Assert.soft`

Answer (score 0):

It common these days to have the solution peppered with `ILogger` dependencies and it would be fine to introduce a dependency on your `IAssert`. Many of the official starter templates from Microsoft come with `ILogger` by default.

Here are out-of-the-box examples for ASP.NET Core Web API (dotnet new webapi) and Azure Functions:

```
public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

```
public static class Function1
{
   [FunctionName("Function1")]
   public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
      [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
      ILogger log)
   {
```

Since at the moment `Assert.Hard` throws if you substitute it with a non throwing code it could very significantly change the behavior or your app. If this is not a concern you could use the actual [ILogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#create-logs) and replace `Assert.Hard` with `logger.LogError` calls and if it is then your `assert.Hard` (no loger `Assert.Hard`) could call `logger.LogError` and throw.

#### Note on local vs remote alerts

Depending on your scenario it may or may not be better to send the email from the client or from the cloud service which receives logs. For example you could configure your log receiver (e.g. Application Insights) to raise an alarm (email) only if there are more than 5 errors of type X in 24h period or any other rule.